# Using physical device to run simple firebase flutter app and getting gradle errors

Tags: firebase, gradle, flutter, dart, stack-trace

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 5 Plus in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\user\proj\android\gradlew.bat" exited 
abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be 
reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\user\proj\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
ASCII
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 3m 22s
Command: C:\user\proj\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ 
folder.
```

But if I comment ***apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'*** in ***proj/app/build.gradle*** it will work perfectly but than firebase is not working.

Comment: add code of your build.gradle app level

Comment: are you building on androidX

Comment: https://github.com/OsamaxD1/Flutter-grale-error-with-firebase and i am using tool (intellij IDE)

Comment: From the GitHub link your project is not on Android X hence the error..latesr firebase dependencies are on Android X.see how to migrate your project to android X https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you write this all dependencies in your file
like
 [CHECK My Github file](https://github.com/hardik584/Flutter-lunchbox/blob/master/android_manifest.dart)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the google-services.json at the right location? (with app-level build.gradle)

Also, check if you have these as dependency in project level build.gradle

> ```
>    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
>    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
> ```

Comment: Yes json file in proj/app Directory and dependencies also added <br/> In proj/build.gradle >classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' >classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2' <br/> And In proj/app/build.gradle >apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-+nmservices' <br/> File added in github link <https://github.com/OsamaxD1/Flutter-grale-error-with-firebase>